# How to animate points being added to a plot in a certain amount of time?

Tags: r, ggplot2, animation, gif, gganimate

I have a `df` containing 10000 data points that I want to add to a plot one by one using `gganimate`. So the data is:

```
df = data.frame(x = runif(10000),
                y = runif(10000),
                z = 1:10000) # z column is needed for transition_states()
```

I created the animation using:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
        geom_point() +
        transition_states(z) +
        shadow_mark() +
        labs(title = "Point num: {closest_state}")
```

But I struggle to get all of my points shown in the animation. For example, I would like to show the points from 1 to 10000 to be added in the animation in about 60-100 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `duration` parameter in the `animate` function.

```r
anim <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  transition_states(z, state_length = 0) +
  shadow_mark() +
  labs(title = "Point num: {closest_state}"

animate(anim, duration = 80, fps = 10000/80, renderer = gifski_renderer())
```

Since you have a lot of points in your dataset, I would suggest to group your point so that you don't end up with 10,000 frames, which takes a lot of time to compute!

Comment: This did not work for me. It only shows up to ~4000 points added, and it is for some reason much longer than 80 seconds.